# How to draw overlay on map in android?

Tags: android, dictionary

I am able to draw a point at particular GEO POINT on map.Now i want to draw overlay on map like [this](http://maps.google.com/maps/ms?vps=2&ie=UTF8&hl=en&oe=UTF8&msa=0&msid=202286927358086676169.0004b4c69b4ec63aee664)

How can i do it ?
I have kmz file containing all info about overlay like list of geo points.
Can any body guide me ?

Answer (score 0):

I used this tutorial. Part two is what you need. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-build-a-mall-finder-app-mapview-location/

Comment: You should summarize linked page to your answer - otherwise when link target page goes down, your answer is worthless.

Comment: I know I will next time. I was on my phone writting this so it was just to much to type it all.